# Qubes OS via VM?

Tags: linux, qubes

I've a question to all the Qubes OS "Knowers" here.
Actually I'm running Linux Mint and I love it. I don't want to change it for my daily routine. It's my fast running system without issues!

Additionally to that I run Whonix in an VM. I love it for the Tor Stuff and it's awesome in security but NOW I found something better for me.

Qubes OS. I love this system, but I don't want to delete Linux Mint System. So I decided to run in an VM and delete my Whonix System in this VM.

Now the question: Is it safe enough or does make Qubes OS sense when I install it on my harddrive?
The problem is: I don't want to restart my system everytime I want to sign in into Tor or in Mint. That's the reason why I changed my habits from Tails OS to Whonix.

Maybe someone can help me with this "problem".

Qubes OS in VM ... yes or better not?

Lovely greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to run Qubes inside a VM. Note the official installation text reads: **We don’t recommend installing Qubes in a virtual machine! It will likely not work.** You can still backup your existing system to an disk image and clean install Qubes. Then you can just make a HVM template of that image to use it again.